# String to MMM-YY format

Tags: python

I am using xlrd to read a spreadsheet and write to a database. However, there is a cell value which needs to be written to a date column in the database.
The cell is a string and I read it as and trying to convert it to MON-YY as follows.

```
    sales_month_val = curr_sheet.cell(1,5).value
    print sales_month_val
    current_sales_month = datetime.strptime(sales_month_val,'%MMM%-%YY%')
```

But I keep getting the conversion failed error message. Is the above conversion to datetime correct to convert to MON-YY format?

Thanks,
bee

Comment: *Is the above conversion to datetime correct to convert to MON-YY format?* obviously not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should take a look at [this strftime reference](http://strftime.org/).

The format you are looking for is:

```
%b-%y
```

Comment: Great. Thank you @Delgan so much for the link. I bookmarked it so I can refer it in future.. %b-%y worked as it should. Thanks again.